# How to use Complex Data Type in c++ API of Tensorflow?

Tags: c++, c++11, tensorflow, complex-numbers

I have been using Tensorflow C++ API for some time now and I have a shared build working so I can load a graph in C++ api and perform simple examples like that shown [here](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f#.wxm2pyrp9). 
I need to make use of Complex Data type of tensorflow in C++ but I can't find any example on that. Can you recommend a very simple usage of complex data type?

Comment: Okay why would anyone downvote this ?     This seems like a very reasonable question that could be useful for many people.       
Just because I am a new user, does not mean I am dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone down-voted you, then I am sorry newbie. 
Stack overflow can be bit weird for new users, but it is a great place for programmers, and you should definitely use it to the best of your abilities.

As for you question, You can simply make use of complex numbers [library](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=c%2B%2B%20complex&oq=c%2B%2B%20complex&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.3129j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

If you have the shared build working then you can try this example(after you adjust the include paths for the necessary files needed)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "tensorflow/core/public/tensor_c_api.h"
#include "tf_session_helper.h"
#include "tf_session_helper.cc"
#include "tf_tensor_helper.cc"
using namespace std;

main()
{ 

    long long adims[] ={3};
    std::complex<double> aData[3]={{1, 2},{3, 4}, {231,452}};     
    auto c = tensorflow::TF_NewTensor_wrapper(TF_DataType::TF_COMPLEX128,adims,(sizeof(adims)/sizeof(*adims)),aData,16*(sizeof(aData)/sizeof(*aData)));
    std::complex<double>* tensor_data = static_cast<std::complex<double>*>(TF_TensorData(c));
    auto dims = TF_NumDims(c);
    auto total_elements = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dims; ++i) {
        total_elements *= TF_Dim(c, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i) {
        cout << std::real(tensor_data[i]) << " " << std::imag(tensor_data[i]) << endl; 
    }

}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.